# Fast way to globally change project references in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with 20+ projects. Pretty much every project references two third party assemblies called foo.v.4.5.dll. I got a new version of the third party application today called foo.v.5.0.dll. I have to visit every project and change the references to the new assemblies. If they don't work well then I have to revisit and undo the change. This is time consuming and a pain.

Is there an easier way to do this? Are there any tools that can help me change the project references globally or is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each project has a `.csproj` file.
These files contains the references to the assemblies.

You can create a code to open all those files, search for the current assembly text and substitute for the new assembly text.

There goes an example:

```
<Reference Include="Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common, Version=18.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eed84259d7cbf30b, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\ObjectARX 2011\inc-win32\Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

So a XML parsing would be probably the best way

Comment: I think creating code is a bit overkill. I'd open all csproj files in Notepad++ (or even in Visual Studio, but you need to unload all projects) and do an all open files replacement.

Comment: That's what I figured I would need to do. Was hoping someone had a simpler approach.

Comment: Do you really need to unload all projects? Why is that needed? Do Visual Studio don't recognize the fact that there are changes if you load the project after editing it?

Comment: @SimonBelanger I was wondering... If that code is run with the `solution closed`, would Visual Studio load all projects with automatic updates next time you `Open Solution`???

Comment: @Lucas If you want to edit a project file, you need to unload the project. Then you need to reload after editing. But maybe if the edit is done with solution closed, next time it's opened the edits come forth with no need to unload.

Comment: @Daniel When a change is made to the `csproj` when the solutions are opened, Visual Studio will prompt you with choices: Accept Changes and Reload Project or Ignore changes.